# Athena query returning different results on different runs when LEAD function was used

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have an Athena table built over S3 and am trying to find lead values for web count on that table. The lead value seems to be changing on different runs and is not consistent.

**web_data Table:**

| id | session_id | date_time | web_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 12:56:03 | 0 |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 12:56:22 | 0 |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 12:58:30 | 0 |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 12:59:22 | 0 |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 13:00:05 | 0 |

**Query used:**

```
select id, session_id, date_time, web_count, 
lead(web_count) over (partition by session_id order by date_time) as next_web_count
from web_data
```

**Results from one run:**

| id | session_id | date_time | web_count | next_web_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 12:56:03 | 0 | 1 |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 12:56:22 | 0 | 0 |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 12:58:30 | 0 | 1 |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 12:59:22 | 0 | 0 |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 13:00:05 | 0 | 0 |

**Results during another run:**

| id | session_id | date_time | web_count | next_web_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 12:56:03 | 0 | 1 |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 12:56:22 | 0 | 0 |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 12:58:30 | 0 | 1 |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 12:59:22 | 0 | 0 |
| 329 | id-123 | 2023-05-01 13:00:05 | 0 | 1 |

Please advice what I can change here to have consistent lead values on Presto.

Comment: The provided sample data can not result in any of the shown outputs. Also note that the last row per partition will always have `null` in `next_web_count`.

Comment: As for different results - it seems that `date_time` is not unique per partition (i.e. the same partition can have several entries for the same `date_time`), so the results are bound to be non-consistent unless you can provide extra ordering.

Comment: If there is a tie in order by column(s) then there is no guarantee which one "leads" the other.

Comment: Thank you. What additional column can I provide for extra ordering considering I have only date time column?

Comment: @SalmanA - There is no tie in order by column which is date time here. Every hit is unique and date time column is always unique here.